# C : how Get OS name ( Ubuntu, Debian,Centos,.. ) and if Definition OS name = ubuntu

Tags: c

I want to write a script with C. Only run on the Ubuntu system.
I Get the name of the operating system. 
But. I failed to define the if clause.
Thanks for the help

Like this algorithm:

[image]

Comment: You might get a better answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are some text files in /etc that could be used: [/etc/os-release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450298/how-to-get-ubuntu-distributions-full-code-name), /etc/issue, /etc/lsb-release (only Ubuntu), /etc/debian_version (Debian+Ubuntu).

Comment: What does "OS name" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most reliable way of checking the OS name is to use the `uname` utility.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int match_OS(const char* name) {
    FILE *p;
    int result;
    char *s = malloc(1024);
    p = popen("uname -v", "r");
    s = fgets(s, 1024, p);
    result = (strstr(s, name) != NULL);
    pclose(p);
    free(s);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    if (match_OS("Ubuntu")) {
        puts("This is Ubuntu");
    }
    else {
        puts("This isn't Ubuntu");
    }
    return 0;
}
```